# Upload queue for data

Tags: java, android

For an android app i'm developing i need to check for an internet connection, before sending data to a web service. It's possible that a device won't be connected to the web for hours, while tasks have to be completed and put into a queue for uploading. Once the device establishes a connection, all of the data has to be transmitted.

I thought about using getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) however that's only possible in an Activity, and for a correct use of OOP, i want to get all of the upload code into a separate class which checks for internet connection, makes a JSON, etc. It also routinely needs to check for a connection to see if the data can be transmitted.

What would be the best way of accomplishing this?

Comment: http://www.chrisdadswell.co.uk/android-coding-example-checking-for-the-presence-of-an-internet-connection-on-an-android-device/